# Snap-store is always running

Tags: snap

I have noticed that `snap-store` in always running in Ubuntu 20.04. Whereas `snapd` service is not, I can’t see it listed in `service --status-all`. I wonder if this is normal because I would like to lessen memory consumption on my machine. And it doesn’t make sense because `snap-store` is a full-fledged application now available from a main menu as ‘Ubuntu software’.

Comment: Please post the output of `pgrep -a` for `snapd` and for `snap-store.`

Comment: For snapd: 841 /usr/lib/snapd/snapd, for snap-store: 2047 /snap/snap-store/433/usr/bin/snap-store --gapplication-service

Comment: I believe this is a bug. I filed a ticket here https://bugs.launchpad.net/snap-store-desktop/+bug/1939527

Answer (score 4):

[The high memory consumption is a known issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/snap-store-desktop/+bug/1879137). You can let the developers know it affects you by logging in and clicking on `This bug affects XXX people. Does this bug affect you?` at the top. It's not a good idea to add a comment there just for this purpose, even after many people already did it.

If, like me, you don't need it, you can uninstall it [as recommended here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1239860/should-the-snap-store-be-using-300mb-of-memory/1262857#1262857) (note you don't need `gnome-software` if you plan to only install snaps from the command line):

```
sudo snap remove snap-store
```