# Should the snap-store be using >300Mb of memory?

Tags: snap, memory-usage

[image: A cropped screenshot showing snap-store in the system monitor window using 355 MiBs of memory.] The `snap-store` process is intermittently using hundreds of megabytes of RAM.

Is this normal? Is there a solution?

Comment: I got pretty high %MEM as well; but killing it via `top` seems to work at least temporarily.

Comment: Also, you can go through https://bugs.launchpad.net/snap-store/+bugs?orderby=-id&start=0 and maybe file a bug? If you do, please ping me so I can #MeToo the bug.

Comment: I just checked the memory used by snap-store in Kubuntu 20.04. It's about 32 MB there, with it open. So it seems like something is amiss with Ubuntu. I've recently not had any response to bugs I've filed so I won't be filing any in this regard for now.

Comment: When it isn't running, there's no `snap-store` process on Kubuntu 20.04.

Comment: I have just copied this questions as a bug report here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/snap-store/+bug/1879137

Comment: sudo snap remove snap-store

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can safely uninstall the Snap Store app with `sudo snap remove snap-store && sudo apt install gnome-software`, and if you do you will still be able to install snap apps from the terminal with `sudo snap install package-name` and also to manage installed snap apps from the terminal.

I don't think Snap Store's excessive RAM usage is anomalous because other Ubuntu users have also reported the same problem. I suggest that you try App Outlet without uninstalling Snap Store. If App Outlet works as a replacement for Snap Store then you can uninstall Snap Store and install the Software app with `sudo apt install gnome-software` instead.

I have both Snap Store and the Software app installed in 20.04 and the RAM used by both apps is freed up when they are closed. I'm worried that your Software app will use excessive memory too, the same as the Snap Store does, but if it may solve half of the problem if it doesn't use excessive memory, and you can use App Outlet alongside the Software app as a replacement for Snap Store.

Comment: Thanks for the quick fix suggestion. I think there is definitely something amiss, and I am not the only one according to the [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/snap-store/+bug/1879137)

Comment: @James Please comment if anything in this answer, which I added new content to, doesn't work properly, so that I can follow up on your comment.

Comment: results of "define anomalous": deviating from what is standard, normal, or expected

Answer (score 3):

This problem is inherited from Gnome Software, see https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-software/-/issues/942 upstream. Hence suggestions to uninstall Snap Store and replace it with Gnome Software won't fit the bill.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah its normal.

If you are not using snap-store just remove it using -

```
sudo snap remove snap-store
```

Instead you can use gnome-software