# Snap-store always running

Tags: snap

I run Ubuntu 20.04. Why is `snap-store` process always running? Is it ok? I'm asking because System monitor show me that is always consuming 281 MB.

Comment: How much RAM does the Snap Store use after running `echo 3 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` to release memory from the cache?

Comment: Same 281 :( @karel

Comment: There is a temporary workaround. [App Outlet](https://app-outlet.github.io/) is  another software center app that has the functionality of searching for snap packages, but if you install it locally in your home directory without root permissions (it is an appimage app) then you have to install snap packages from the terminal. If App Outlet is locally installed the RAM it used should be freed up when it is closed.

Comment: what are you suggesting me is  remove snap-store and install app Outlet? Is my snap-sotre's consumption anomalous ? Thanks for everything :) @karel

Comment: [What is an “AppImage”? How do I install it?](https://askubuntu.com/q/774490/). I don't think Snap Store's excessive RAM usage is anomalous because other Ubuntu users have also reported the same problem. I suggest that you try App Outlet without uninstalling Snap Store. If App Outlet works as a replacement for Snap Store then you can uninstall Snap Store and install the Software app with `sudo apt install gnome-software` instead. Please comment about the results of using gnome-software whether there is excessive memory usage like the Snap Store.

Comment: I have both Snap Store and the Software app installed in 20.04 and the RAM used by both apps is freed up when they are closed. I'm worried that your Software app will use excessive memory too, the same as the Snap Store does, but if it may be an answer if it doesn't use excessive memory.

Comment: Actually, I have snap store and gnome-software  process always running (I mean, even after they are closed) gnome-software consume 110 MB, so I didn't put too much attention. I killed the procces, and snap-store didn't appear again, but gnome-software did. I will try the App Outlet :) Anyway, this days I have had a lot of trouble with the "software" app (I have to add that snap-store don't even appear in my apps I only have Ubuntu software and plain "software") so trying another option could resolve many other problems :) @karel

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111339/discussion-between-karel-and-rnopalzin).

Comment: I am also finding that snap-store is frequently running. It seems that starting the ubuntu software app starts the snap-store process, but the process doesn't exit when the ubuntu software app is closed. I haven't figured out if that is the only thing that causes it to start running. On my machine, I've seen snap-store consume as much as 450MiB.

Comment: I would like to add that, after changing to Xubuntu environment, this problem doesn't occur anymore.

Comment: There is another discussion about the snap-store memory usage issue here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1239860/should-the-snap-store-be-using-300mb-of-memory

Comment: This problem is inherited from Gnome Software, see https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-software/-/issues/942 upstream. Hence suggestions to uninstall Snap Store and replace it with Gnome Software won't fit the bill.

Comment: @karel Don't know what to tell. Is that question referring even when the app is closed (Is It what the user means with "intermittently")? If it is, then yes we are asking the same and I should close this one (though neither question has a proper answer).