# snap-store taking a lot of ram

Tags: software-center, snap

As the title says `snap-store` is taking a lot of ram (about 300MB). Is there a way I can avoid this?

I'm on ubuntu 20.04

Comment: No, when I try to remove snap-store, it gives this error --> `E: Unable to locate package snap-store
`

Comment: Try `sudo snap remove snap-store`

Comment: Can I use the snap apps after using that command?

Comment: Using snap apps and managing snap packages does not depend in any way on the Snap Store application being installed.

Comment: It worked, thanks. And then I tried `sudo apt install gnome-software` to install apps, and now `gnome-software takes more than 300MB`

Comment: My gnome-software takes >300MB memory in 20.04 too. It might have something to do with the Software app checking for updates to installed snap packages.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should the snap-store be using >300Mb of memory?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1239860/should-the-snap-store-be-using-300mb-of-memory)